# Edge deletion game on a graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, contest-math, game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

I thought up the following two player game on a graph.

> A graph $G$ is given as an input. Each player deletes one edge in turn. The one who makes an isolated vertex first wins.

I would like to know how to decide the winner and his strategy.

It is easy to see that the vertices with degree $1$ or $2$ are not needed.
But I don't know further about this game even for simple graphs.

I would appreciate it if you would give me some observations or comments or related works or whatever.

Comment: Notice that the first player must deleted edges from vertices with odd degree only

Comment: Are you saying that if $G$ is Eulerian, then second player wins.

Comment: Not necessarily. I am saying that the first player needs to delete edges emitting from vertices of an odd degree. This also highlights the fact that if all vertices are of degree $2$ then the second player is guaranteed to win.

Comment: Could you explain why the first player has to delete the edge incident to the vertices with  odd degree?

Comment: By even odd parity, it is easy to see that player 1 makes the odd move (1st turn, 3rd turn....)

Comment: What happens if the first player deletes the edge emitting from a vertex of even degree?
How the second player wins in this case?

Comment: If the first player deletes an even edge, then player 2 can delete an odd edge, if this continues on a particular vertex then player 2 wins

Comment: @h-squared I wrote some code and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZpkK.png) is the first counterexample to your claim. The highlighted edge is a winning move for the first player; deleting any edges out of odd degree vertices loses.